# How does a car move on a banked turn without friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

Do the tires rotate while a car getting around a banked curve without friction?

Comment: Welcome.  What do you exactly mean by banked turn or banked curve? Do you mean that the shift gear is in - or the wheels (tires) are not connected to the  transmission (motor) in any way?

Comment: Be nice to a new member and write the reasons for downvotes friends :).

Comment: @Evgenii Is there anything inherently not "nice" about downvotes?  Users opinions about questions are just that, opinions.  It's not a personal dink against the person asking it.  People are allowed to use their votes to say "I don't think this is a good question"; and they don't need to write a reason when they do it.  Downvotes on questions also don't have an effect on reputation directly.  Please don't try to generate your own rules or perpetuate the idea that downvoting is somehow malicious.

Comment: @JMac - downvotes on a question do affect reputation (well, maybe not if your reputation is at 1). And if the first encounter with the site is that your question is received negatively, it can be disconcerting. A "welcome" message like jaromax posted can be augmented with "I don't think this is a great question as written because...". This would be far less intimidating for a new user. Yes, you don't _have_ to do it; but Evgenii asked (nicely) for people to be kind. "Be nice to people" is actually a rule of this site.

Comment: @Floris I just think the sentiment that "Downvoting without comments isn't nice" doesn't make sense to me; and statements like that make it worse.  We aren't downvoting the person, nor is anyone doing it to be mean.  I don't think it's productive do leave a comment saying "Be nice and leave a reason for downvotes" because the first point is already a rule, and the second point is purely an opinion, has nothing to do with the question, and was already deemed unnecessary in meta.  Leaving comments implying that the downvote was negative or not nice could make users think that's the truth.

Comment: @JMac Evgenii didn't say "it's not nice not to..." - he said "it's nice to...". Also - a downvote literally puts the score in the negative - how is that not "negative"? But we're splitting hairs here. We've voiced our opinions, I think the OP got some help, let's move on.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Your title and your text appear to be two different questions. You need to provide more explain about what is bothering you.

Comment: Consider how a bobsled or a luge move around a curve? What would happen to them if the curves were not banked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no friction, whether the wheels are rolling or locked doesn't matter. At the same time, if there is no friction it is impossible to steer (there would be no lateral force on the car if you turn the wheels - a disconcerting experience you may have had in a car when you hit a patch of black ice).

On a frictionless surface, any object in a banked turn will go "wherever the forces take it" - this means there will be only one velocity with which you can enter the turn which will allow you to come out and still be in the middle of the road.

Comment: I can understand that car can take the turn without friction as there is centripetal force. But the thing I don't realize is how do the wheels rotate without friction?

Comment: Wheels rotate if the engine makes them rotate - and they don't if it doesn't. Without friction, the real question is "how did the car ever accelerate?"... This is the problem with "theoretical" physics questions like this. You are right to ponder this - but don't break your head over it.

Comment: Yeah the engine can rotate them. But the car won't move without friction. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well - there are other ways a car can move: it could slide down a hill, it could be pushed, there might be wind... but yes, a car won't be moved by its engine if the engine can only apply force through the wheels, and there is no friction.

Answer (score 0):

The simple analysis of motion on a banked track makes the assumption that it is a point mass going around a bend.
From such an analysis an angle for the banking can be found such that the force causing the centripetal acceleration is entirely provided by the horizontal component of the normal reaction and none from a frictional force between the mass and the banking.
This is very much an ideal situation with no friction, no extended object and no wheels present.

Once you have four wheels on the corners of an extended object (or two on a motorbike) the analysis becomes more complex and the object will not go around a banked track without friction being present.
Even the smallest deviation from the ideal banking trajectory would necessitate a path correction which could not be achieved without friction.

To maintain a constant speed due to air resistance there must be a force on the object in the forward direction and this would provided by an engine via the wheels which thus must be rotating.

All in all in the real world there are banked tracks and if the speed and angle of the banking are just about “correct” hands can be taken off the steering wheel and reasonable control of the car can be maintained by using the accelerator but that is only possible with friction present and the wheels of the car rotating.

Answer (score -2):

There is no banked turn without friction. Think Newtons first law of motion.

Comment: But we have it in the syllabus.

Comment: @Aurora Is it "without friction" or "without **kinetic** friction"?

Comment: This is incorrect. It *is* possible for a car to turn on a banked turn without any friction at all as the normal force is not vertical and can therefore deviate the car from a horizontal straight line.

Comment: Then do the tires rotate? And how?

Comment: @Aurora Without friction the car will move in a straight line in the direction where it last had contact with the surface. The tyres / wheels will only rotate if you have your foot on the gas pedal but without friction will have no effect. Have you never seen a video of a car on ice? It doesn't matter if the turn is banked or not. Any other proposition goes against newtons first law.

Comment: @PeterS "Without friction the car will move in a straight line in the direction where it last had contact with the surface" but the surface itself isn't a straight line here.

Comment: The car would follow a straight line that forms  the radius of the curve of the banked road. That is if your banked road is like the surface of a shallow cone. The question itself is about some fictional scenario that will only confuse a student. If you could somehow remove friction from the scenario the car would be in collision with the road. The question is not about a gravitational force on an object in free space.